# How to implement styling in page?

Tags: wordpress

I am making custom h1 styling menu for customize panel in wordpress site but I don't know how to include the custom h1 styles in html structure of page.

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'h1_styles' , array(
'title'      => __('H1 Styles','wptthemecustomizer'), 
'panel'      => 'design_settings',
'priority'   => 100    
) );  

$wp_customize->add_setting(
  'wpt_h1_color',
  array(
      'default'         => '#222222',
      'transport'       => 'postMessage'
  )
 );

 $wp_customize->add_control(
   new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
       $wp_customize,
       'custom_h1_color',
       array(
           'label'      => __( 'Color', 'wptthemecustomizer' ),
           'section'    => 'h1_styles',
           'settings'   => 'wpt_h1_color' 
       )
   )
  );
```

I know I have to do something like this :-

```
     if( get_theme_mod( 'wpt_h1_color') != "" ): 
        /* code */
     endif;
```

But I want to know should I apply styles directly in html in head section with the above code or It can be done through function in functions.php.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in html outputing `<style></style>` and some css in there (which is faster than loading external files, and Google Speed Insights maybe not recommends, but approves that way). You can also wp_enqueue_style() if you want to.